# Extending remote session count

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use `Invoke-Command` to run multiple query on a remote server as a PowerShell job. But I could see that on a single server it can not run more than 25 job instances. Any idea how I can increase the limit? I did try setting max shell per user to 50, but no help.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($com in $hostcomp) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $com -ScriptBlock {
        cd WSMan:\localhost\Shell
        dir
        Set-Item .\MaxShellsPerUser 1000
        dir
        Set-Item .\MaxProcessesPerShell 1000
        dir
    }
    Get-VM -ComputerName $com | Select -ExpandProperty name |
        Out-File c:\vmfile.txt
    $vm = Get-Content "c:\vmfile.txt"
    foreach ($v in $vm) {
        Write-Host $v " on $com is being SHUTDOWN..................Please Wait!"
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $com -ScriptBlock {
            param($v)
            Stop-VM -name $v -Force
        } -ArgumentList $v -AsJob -JobName "ShutDownVMsss"
    }
}
```

After 25 jobs on each remote server it fails with the error max number of allowed session for user has exceeded.

Comment: Include sample code so we don't have to ask questions such as if the jobs are running locally or remotely.

Comment: Just to confirm, these are different servers you're running this across? Because with default settings I can run 40 invokes across two different servers without error, as long as neither exceeds 25

Comment: Yes, i am running this code across different servers, from one server. Like there are 20 servers, on each server having 50+ Vm's , but on each server I could see only 25 jobs running rest all jobs fails with max connection error. even though i had configured max shell to 100+..

Comment: Consider using [runspaces](http://learn-powershell.net/2012/05/13/using-background-runspaces-instead-of-psjobs-for-better-performance/) instead of jobs.

Answer (score 1):

wsman:\localhost\shell\MaxShellsPerUser sets the global quota - which is the total quota for all endpoints put together. When you create a remote session it is created by default against Microsoft.PowerShell The quota for that needs to be increased as well under WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\microsoft.powershell\Quotas\MaxShellsPerUser (*the default is 25*)